# Can I park a car with camping trailer attached somewhere at Curry Village while staying in a tent cabin?

Tags: automobiles, camping, national-parks

I have a "tent cabin" reservation at Curry Village (near Yosemite National Park in the US).  My trip involves a lot of other camping situations and I will be in a mini-SUV pulling a small camping trailer.  I want to be sure that it's ok for me to park the car with the trailer there while I am staying there.

- I do not have a reservation for an RV/trailer site at Curry Village
- I do have a reservation for a "tent cabin", so I can legitimately stay overnight
- I want to know if wherever you park your car when you stay in a "tent cabin" allows a trailer to be attached to the car

At the [National Park Service site](https://www.nps.gov/yose/planyourvisit/rv.htm), it addresses RV parking but not trailer-attached-to-my-car parking.  There is a site map at a site called [Travel Yosemite](https://www.travelyosemite.com/media/823975/curry-village-property-map-20190802.pdf) but the parking that is available in the campground looks like single car parking.  I don't want to travel 1500 miles to get there and be turned away because I can't park there with my trailer.  Does anyone know if my situation can be accommodated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have a number of options for parking at/near Curry Village.  Exactly which are available will depend on the time of day you arrive, and especially during the middle of the day on a weekend in peak season you may need to wait a little to find a park.

What is described as the "Apple Tree Orchard Visitor Parking" on the map you've linked to is actually large open carpark where vehicles park nose-to-nose, however for most of the parking there are no barriers between the vehicles. Thus you will be able to simply pull through and take up 2 spots.  If you go to [Google Maps](https://goo.gl/maps/S9uhbnXb6c7LjzNB7) and enable Satellite view you'll be able to get a good idea of what I mean - and you can even see an RV parked in the upper part of this parking in that view.  The only potential issue with this is that depending on the time of day you may not be able to find 2 parks together.

Secondly, there is a dedicated RV parking area in the north-western corner of that same parking lot (the bottom right as shown on your linked map - close to the "14" marker.  Despite not being an RV I would not expect you to have any problems parking there if you are too large to fit in any other parking spots.  This area has the advantage that there are often spots available at times when you may not find 2 spots available elsewhere in the lot.

The third option is along Happy Isles Loop Road - in the bottom left area of the map you've linked. Parking is available along one side of that road for most of it's length.

Note that the map you've linked to has two issues.  Firstly, it's upside-down!  North is pointing towards the bottom!  There's not necessarily anything wrong with that, but keep it in mind when trying to orient yourself, especially if comparing to Google Maps.

Secondly, the map is a little out of date.  The stretch of Happy Isles Loop Road which is located below the "Curry Village" label/emblem will most likely be closed off and not passable as shown.  They changed this a few years ago, and whilst it's possible it will be changed back again, it's likely you will need to turn right off Southside Drive onto Curry Village Drive in order to access any of the locations mentioned above.

Comment: I really appreciate this answer.  Much of the parking your are identifying seems to me to be primarily for day use.  Is it correct that as long as you have a camping site reserved you can part in any of those places overnight?

Comment: Curry Village is not considered a "camp site". However all of those area are available for parking overnight, both by people in Curry Village but also at the nearby camping grounds. The Apple Tree area is the main Curry Village overnight parking lot.